# Google App Engine - Service accounts import error

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I am struggling to understand why I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandlerhandler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObjectobj = __import__(path[0])
File "/base/data/home/apps/g~email-report-receiver/1.407675116246966578/main.py", line 20, in <module>
from google.auth import app_engine
ImportError: No module named auth
```

And I am following this guide: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts
(see the *Google App Engine standard environment section*)

Given that I am directly copying a line of code: `from google.auth import app_engine` from Google's guide and the code is running on an App-Engine Standard Environment, why am I getting an import error?

---

Here is my requirements.txt file:

```
google-api-python-client
google-auth
google-auth-httplib2
```

And my app_engine.py file:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('google-auth')
vendor.add('google-auth-httplib2')
vendor.add('google-api-python-client')
```

Still getting the same error as above.

Comment: Found my error in importing the external libraries, I had named the file app_engine.py instead of appengine_config.py